# functions with touch

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why doesn't the following work?

```
function xyz(){ touch $1; }
xyz temp1.txt
```

I get an error

```
touch: missing file operand
Try `touch --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux at StackExchange! I just tried your two exact commands on bash and it worked for me... Can you double check your setup? Try `type xyz` to see what bash thinks the definition of your function is...

Comment: Did you perhaps run something more interesting, like `xyz "file name with spaces"`?

Comment: Sorry! It worked fine. Thank you for quick (and kind) responses.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ function xyz() { touch "$1"; }
$ xyz temp1.txt
$ ls temp1.txt
temp1.txt
```